# How to use Map and FlatMap - Java 8

Tags: java

How can I use `map` and `flatMap` in my example?

I have a class `UserProfile` that looks like this:

```
public class UserProfile {
    public final UserId userId;
    public final Optional<AffordabilityCheck> affordabilityCheck;
```

From `UserProfile` class I should access `AffordabilityCheck` class that looks like this:

```
public class AffordabilityCheck {
    public final RiskGroup riskGroup;
}
```

From `AffordabilityCheck` class I should get `riskGroup` which is an enum and looks like this:

```
public enum RiskGroup {
    LOW,
    LOW_MEDIUM,
    MEDIUM,
    MEDIUM_HIGH,
    HIGH
}
```

And return it as `String` variable

I tried something like this:

```
String riskGroup = userProfile.flatMap(ac -> ac.getAffordabilityCheck()).map(gr -> gr.getRiskGroup().name());
```

But I get error:

```
Required type:
String

Provided:
Optional<java.lang.Object>
```

How can I do this with `map` and `flatMap`?

Comment: I assume [you first spent some time](/help/how-to-ask) reading up on how Map and Flatmap work, and looked at examples of their use, so: given what that taught you, what is unclear about how to apply them to your own code? Because Stackoverflow [is not for](/on-topic) teaching you how to program ;)

Comment: Actually I did. Wouldn't post the question if I came to a conclusion from what I have read. It's not about solving the problem for me/someone is "helping to show the way". I thought StackOverflow is about that, or me, and you interpret it in wrong way ;)

Comment: What is `riskProfile`? To get better help please provide actual [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (a.k.a. [MCVE])

Comment: Sorry its user profile... spelling mistake

Comment: odd, so it is. It was supposed to point to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @user9347049 you're expected to explain what you already did in your post, including whether you looked up how to use something you have questions about. No one knows you did your "searching and researching" if you don't tell them. So if you looked up the docs and examples, then posting is fine as long as you also show what you already tried, because you know how they're used, you know your own code, you should have at least tried to write some code based on that knowledge and it didn't work, so show what you tried and talk about how that didn't do what you thought it would.

Comment: Yes, I did provided my code or example of what I have tried to do. It is in question. Yes, maybe I should have told that I researched I will keep it in mind for future :)

Comment: "Sorry its user profile... spelling mistake" are you sure ? Your `public class UserProfile {` doesn't show any `flatMap` method, not it should have it. Usually it is invoked from `Stream` not on instance of some class. Again, to avoid confusion it would be best to post actual [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (a.k.a. [MCVE])

Comment: Also please remember to use proper formatting for code: single ticks are for inline code (e.g., talking about `variable` or `function` inside a sentence), if you're showing actual source code, remember to use code fences (triple ticks on their own line) or the older "four spaces in front", so that the proper syntax highlighting gets applied (inline code does not get syntax highlighting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code compiles, I would guess that you start with an Optional of UserProfile. Something like this should work:

```
String riskGroup = userProfile.flatMap(UserProfile::getAffordabilityCheck)
            .map(AffordabilityCheck::getRiskGroup)
            .map(Enum::name)
            .orElse("");
```

The reason you get this error is that you did not "unpack" the value froma an Optional, and tried to save the riskGroup variable as an Optional of String. You should check the orElse, orElseGet, get and getOrElseThrow methods. Please keep in mind that using Optional#get may end up throwing an NoSuchElementException if the Optional is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Streaming is for taking a series of similar items and putting them in a "pipe line" for processing.  I am presuming you have a `List<UserProfile>` since you want to use stream (and your UserProfile class doesn't show a `flatMap` method).

```
List<UserProfile> userProfile = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        new UserProfile(Optional.of(
                new AffordabilityCheck(RiskGroup.MEDIUM))),
        new UserProfile(Optional.empty()),
        new UserProfile(Optional
                .of(new AffordabilityCheck(RiskGroup.LOW))),
        new UserProfile(
                Optional.ofNullable(null)),
        new UserProfile(Optional.of(
                new AffordabilityCheck(RiskGroup.HIGH)))));
```

In this case, using `flatMap` is not necessary.

- first filter out checks that are not present.
- then return the name of those that are.
- and append to a string, separated by commas. You could also return a list of those strings here via `toList()` instead of the `joining` collector.

```
String result = userProfile.stream()
        .filter(up -> up.affordabilityCheck.isPresent())
        .map(opt -> opt.affordabilityCheck.get().riskGroup
                .name())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
MEDIUM, LOW, HIGH
```

If on the other hand you had a single instance of UserProfile you can do this

```
UserProfile userProfile = some instance
```

- This maps the optional to the desired string if present, otherwise, if the affordabilithCheck contains an `empty` or `nullable` optional, this returns a string informing you of its absence.

```
String result = userProfile.affordabilityCheck
        .map(opt -> opt.riskGroup.name())
        .orElse("AffordabiltyCheck not found");
```